# external config based on context path

Tags: spring, tomcat

I would like to deploy multiple independent copies of a particular web-app on the same tomcat server under different context paths. Each web-app will need different configuration settings (database name, password, etc), but I would like to keep the wars exactly identical.

My plan was to have the app figure out its context path on startup, then read a specific .properties file outside of tomcat identified by the context path. For example, if a war was deployed to {tomcat path}/webapps/pineapple, then I would want to read /config/pineapple.properties

I've been trying to find a way to inject an instance of ServletContext via spring (3), but all the advice I've seen so far use the deprecated ServletContextFactoryBean.

Is there a better way to get the context path injected or better way to load external files based on the context path?

Comment: can i ask why you want to do this?

Comment: i have an application that is used by multiple users, independent of one another. the application is identical across all users, the only difference being the database connection specifics. i'd like to only have to build one war that knows how to find the right config based on the servlet context path (or some other external meta data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extend Propertyplaceholderconfigurer to use DB to pick up the values. Example [here](http://knol.google.com/k/kamal-kumar/loading-application-properties-from-a/1ewa3fwfhc8oq/1#)
2. Load the actual values of the settings (database name, password etc) to the db as part of seed data
3. When your web-app's app ctx is being initialized, the properties are resolved from the DB

This is the approach we have been following and works great. If you can switch to Spring 3.1 then it has support for [Environment Profiles](http://grahamhackingscala.blogspot.com/2010/10/spring-31-whats-new-springone-juergen.html) which may be useful for you.

Comment: I don't see how the servlet context path is being referenced here. In order for two identical wars to load distinct config files/settings based on the servlet context path, it seems to me there's got to be something that reads the servlet context path, which I don't see in that example. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: i've found something related - ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. seems like it should be something that would know about the servlet context path... but i'm not having any luck

Answer (score 5):

With the help of `ServletContextAttributeFactoryBean` and Spring EL, you can reference ServletContext init parameters (`<context-param>` in web.xml) like that:

```
#{contextAttributes.myKey}
```

This allows you to use `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` and load property files from arbitrary, user-defined locations:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="#{contextParameters.APP_HOME}/conf/app.properties"/>
</bean>
```

The corresponding definition of the ServletContext init parameter in Tomcat's context.xml:

```
<Parameter name="APP_HOME" value="file:/test" override="false"/>
```

Or in your app's web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>APP_HOME</param-name>
    <param-value>file:/test</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be the solution.

```
<bean name="envConfig" class="EnvironmentConfiguration">
     <property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>file:///#{servletContext.contextPath}.properties</value>
    </list>
     </property>
     <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```